# Store data in a xml file in Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, php, xml, configuration

I have a module that has some input fields in admin. One of the input is an ID that will use the same value every time, so I don't want to display that input in admin anymore to avoid changing or deleting it (i'm not the only one who has access to the admin panel). I talk to a friend and he tells me to put it in a configuration **xml** file and take it from there. It is possible to do that? How can I create a new **xml** file and take that value from there? Can anyone help me please?

Comment: You can also answer your own question and mark it as accepted answer. So it will be useful for other users.

Comment: I didn't know that. It is ok if I answer now and I delete my edit?

Comment: Yes it is perfectly fine. If a question has an accepted answer, it will be highlighted in question list and search results, so any user looking for an answer will know that there is an answer to the question and it is accepted as correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, after I search on the internet for a couple of days I finally managed to resolve my problem.

First I created a xml file in etc folder that looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
     <appid>app_id_here</appid>
</config>
```

To take the id from the file I use this code:

```
$configFile = Mage::getConfig()->getModuleDir('etc', 'Module_Name').DS.'file.xml';
$string = file_get_contents($configFile);
$xml = simplexml_load_string($string, 'Varien_Simplexml_Element');
echo $xml->appid;
```

I hope in the future this will help some people.